# Sitecore: How to deny access to items outside the Site Root Item

Tags: c#, sitecore

I'm trying to hide items in the Content tree outside of my Site Root item so that they become inaccessible by URL.

Two of my approaches did not work:

The first one was to play with  settings in Web.config

```xml
<sites>
    <site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/home" startItem="/" database="web" .../>
</sites>
```

This could solve the problem, but LinkManager started to raise exceptions. As startItem is empty, it tries to make a Substring from an empty string, it crashes.

The second try was to implement an ItemNotFound processor so that if my Item is not SiteRoot or its descendant, it sets Context item to null and makes the 404 routine.

```
public class ItemNotFoundHandler : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (Sitecore.Context.Item != null && Sitecore.Context.Site.Name == "website")
        {
            Item siteroot = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Settings.SiteRootID);

            if (Sitecore.Context.Item.ID != siteroot.ID && !Sitecore.Context.Item.Axes.IsDescendantOf(siteroot))

                //Do404();
                Sitecore.Context.Item = null;
        }

        if (Sitecore.Context.Item != null  || Sitecore.Context.Site == null || Sitecore.Context.Database == null)
            return;



        Do404();
    }

    private void Do404()
    {
        Item item404 = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Settings.Error404ID);
        Sitecore.Context.Item = item404;
    }
}
```

This didn't change anything: the Context item stays unchanged. I cannot understand why.

Can you help me out?

Comment: Where in the httprequest pipeline do you hook this processor up?

Comment: just after the ItemResolver

Comment: `Sitecore.Context.Item.Axes.IsDescendantOf()` *shudders* - This will be a performance issue. Use `Sitecore.Context.Item.Paths.FullPath.StartsWith(Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath)` instead for that entire section. Rest looks like it should work. If you add breakpoints are they being hit?

Comment: yes, breakpoint is hit, Do404() is executed, but then I still have the item rendered as if nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. I decompiled the Sitecore LinkProvider and saw where the problem was.

The first approach was correct, with only one remark: startItem should be empty.

The "/" symbol is taken into account when calculating rootPath, its length becomes one symbol too big, and it throws OutOfRangException. If I remove this symbol or remove startItem at all, there is no more problem.

```xml
<sites>
    <site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/home" startItem="" database="web" .../>
</sites>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to be able to browse to items outside the `Home` node, what you could do is have those items not have any presentation details.

You can then change the setting `LayoutNotFoundUrl` to your 404 page:

```
<setting name="LayoutNotFoundUrl" value="/My404" />
```

If you do want to have presentation details on those nodes for whatever reason, or if the above doesn't work for any different reason, why not just call your 404 page in the Do404 method?

```
private void Do404()
{
    Item item404 = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Settings.Error404ID);
    Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.Redirect(LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item404));
}
```